# Python Pandas DataFrame Reindexing a certain data from 0

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

My code is given below: I extracted a part of data from original dataframe. I wanted the newdata frame to have index starting from 0. Strangely, it carries the old index with it. I tried the `reset_index()`, but it didn't work. Any inputs?

```
a = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
a = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=['Data'])
print(a)
b = pd.DataFrame(a['Data'][3:5])
print(b)
b.reset_index()
print(b)
```

The output is:

```
      Data
0    10
1    20
2    30
3    40
4    50
5    60
   Data
3    40
4    50
   Data
3    40
4    50
```

I was expecting the index of `b` dataframe to be as:

```
Data
0    40
1    50
```

I tried the following code as suggested by `jezrael` which is my accepted answer and it perfectly worked:

```
b.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
print (b)
```

The new output is:

```
    Data
0    40
1    50
```

But, I don't want index column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forget assign back and add `drop=True` parameter for remove original `index`:

```
b = b.reset_index(drop=True)
print(b)
   Data
0    40
1    50
```

Or use:

```
b.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
print(b)
   Data
0    40
1    50
```

---

If not use `drop=True` is created new column  with original index values:

```
b = b.reset_index()
print(b)
   index  Data
0      3    40
1      4    50
```

Comment: `jezrael` it's great. It worked perfectly. I am new to python. Could you explain what is the significance of `(inplace=True, drop=True)`. I tried these two arguements individually. But, they gave same result. But, when used together as suggested by you, it gave answer as I wanted. Please, some explanation for my understanding?

Comment: @Msquare - sure. `inplace=True` parameter is possible use in more function in pandas and working same. Function working `inplace`, it means it performs the operation and returns a copy of the object  and also it return `None`, check `b = b.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)` and `print (b)`